# Can't connect to Ember store (Ember CLI)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Ember app, using Ember CLI, ember-data and http-mock.
I can't seem to connect to the store from the clubs/index route.

[image]

This seems to be the offending code. If I remove the call to the store, and include an inline model everything works fine. Nop idea why it can't find the store.

```
// clubs/index.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('club');
    }
});
```

The http-mock works just fine when I curl it:

```
curl -H "ContentType:application/json" http://localhost:4200/api/clubs
```

Everything else is pretty standard:

```
// router.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('clubs', function() {

    });
});

export default Router;

// club.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks to be that your app is hitting `/clubs` while your api is located at `/api/clubs`.  To fix this you can create an ApplicationAdapter in `app/adapters/application.js` to properly namespace your api:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Comment: So simple. Worked.Thanks!